# Is there any other latin translation for the english term, "Butterfly" aside from Papilio?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary

For some reason I was looking through my older notes on Latin translations and saw that *Gloria* worked as a translation for *Butterfly*.

I've been looking all through the net to confirm my suspicions but have stumbled across nothing so far.

With that said, is *Gloria* another term for *Butterfly* or is there any other Latin term for *Butterfly*?

Comment: Do [scientific names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly#Taxonomy_and_phylogeny) count?

Comment: @Rafael seems good!

Comment: Do you have the actual citation for this use of _gloria_?  All references to butterflies that I can find in the corpus use only _papilio_ and so I wondered if your notes were perhaps a reference to some sort of metaphor, rather than an actual synonym for butterfly.  Phaedrus, for example, has a fable about a butterfly and a wasp which could conceivably be about former glory and/or boastfulness.  More explicitly, other, later authors would compare vain and proud people to butterflies.

Comment: I checked around and it seems like I don't have anything listed regarding this - I am curious about the fable you mention though @Penelope

Comment: Here you go :) http://mythfolklore.net/aesopica/oxford/199.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vergil Georg. IV 205, speaking not of butterflies but of honey bees, mentions their tantus amor florum et generandi gloria mellis. Is there perhaps a confusion of the species?

Comment: it seems more and more likely that I must have been confused when writing Gloria in regards to butterflies, thanks for the mention about bees